# Ubuntu won't wake up from suspend

Tags: suspend, power-management, 18.04, bug-reporting, debugging

When I suspend my Ubuntu (version 18.04), it doesn't wake up by clicking buttons or anything (even though I do hear the computer is on). Only option I have is to power it off and on.

*My computer info:*

- MSI laptop model: MS-1781

*What I've tried:*

- Update the OS with the following commands:

  ```
  sudo apt update
  sudo apt upgrade
  sudo apt dist-upgrade
  ```
- Use NVidia proprietary software
- Tried version 16.04, still doesn't work
- Edited the GRUB file with different online recommendations, non of which worked
- Tried pressing random keys when suspended, like ALT + Control + Backspace, nothing

**QUESTION:**
- Does anyone have any possible solutions to this? I don't want to go back to windows. But this is so inconvenient, that I have to power it off all the time. It really sucks, and I see a lot of people having similar problems online :(

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried pressing the power button for a second or so?

I have a Lenovo X1 Carbon that has the same issue: it won't wake via any keypresses, or pressing the power button for a short time, but seems to wake fine with a long press.

Not sure if that is a bug or a feature...